# Android set layout_weight to width in vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I got a vertical LinearLayout, in which there's a button. I want to make this button 70% of the width of the LinearLayout and center it.

I've tried setting `layout_weight` to 0.7 while setting the `layout_width` to 0, but since it's a vertical LinearLayout, it doesn't affect the width, but can only affect the height.

How can I change the weight of the width in a vertical layout? Will I must add a nesting horizontal LinearLayout just for the button so I can set its weight?

Comment: Send me your xml code.

Comment: and other 30% layout you have to give `0dp` width and `0.3` weight.

Comment: post your XML code.

Comment: nested horizontal linear layout seems the only option to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using new [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html), and you can achieve what you are trying without nested layouts.

include this in your dependencies :`com.android.support:percent:25.1.0`

And then in your code

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  ...

 <Button
       app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  ...

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a percent linear layout?

Comment: I know I can just tell widgets to below another widget but I'm trying to avoid it and just let the layout set it itself like the linearlayout do

Comment: why are you trying avoid it ? its the same thins linearLayout will do, except you need to specify it

Comment: Just for the sake of future more comfortable work. Obviously I could have done it by now, but just to save some writings in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
linearLayout -> orientation = horizontal
button -> layout width = 0dp
       -> layout height = wrap_content
       -> layout weight = 1
```

Comment: but I need the layout vertical, not horizontal

Comment: you can try setting the width of the button to match_parent, and add margins both left and right, or use a nested layout

Comment: Does setting the margins like this on both sides considered a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yourRequiredButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Space android:layout_weight=0.15/>
    <Button android:layout_weight=0.7/>
    <Space android:layout_weight=0.15/>
</LinearLayout>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html

I also suggest you put the values in `dimens.xml` file.